# getDeclaredMethod doesn't work, NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

I've been trying to use `Reflection` in Java, but it doesn't end up pretty well. Here's my code:

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReflectionTest test = new ReflectionTest();
        try {
            Method m = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("Test");
            m.invoke(test.getClass(), "Cool story bro");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Test(String someawesometext) {
        System.out.println(someawesometext);
    }
}
```

I just get the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` error, and I've tried pretty much everything. 
Like using `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`, add `test.getClass()` after `"Test"` in `getDeclaredMethod` and more.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ReflectionTest.Test()
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
at ReflectionTest.main(ReflectionTest.java:10)
```

I have been Googling for many days now but with no luck. So I does anyone know how I'm supposed to fix this?

Comment: This might not solve the issue, but you should be invoking the method on your instance, `test`, rather than `test.getClass()`.

Comment: You should also pass array of classes of params as argument.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You specify a name in `getDeclaredMethod` but no parameter, although the `Test` method does have a parameter in its signature.

Try this:

```
Method m = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("Test", String.class);
```

along with this:

```
m.invoke(test, "Cool story bro");
```

Because the first argument of [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) expects an object. However this argument is ignored in case of static methods:

> If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is
>   ignored. It may be null.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

Problem 1 is you must soecify HHS parameter signature of the target method:

```
Method m = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("Test", String.class);
```

Problem 2 is you must pass the instance to the `invoke()`  method:

```
m.invoke(test, "Cool story bro");
```

FYI you *would* pass the `class` of the instance as the target to the `invoke` method if the method were `static`.

Comment: @assylias yeah... I've always preferred passing the class - it seems "right" somehow, because it feels like the class object should be the target.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JavaDoc for Class.getDeclaredMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) you can see that it expects a parameter type array.

Answer (score 0):

```
        final Class<?> ContextImpl =Class.forName("android.app.ContextImpl");
        Method method= ContextImpl.getDeclaredMethod("getImpl",Context.class); 
        method.setAccessible(true);  
        Context myContext=  (Context) method.invoke(ContextImpl,getApplicationContext());                     
        System.out.println("........... Private Method Accessed. : "+myContext);
```