# getDeclaredMethod in Java Fails

Tags: java

I have a batch app which uses a file input with the method names and then the names are used to execute a method with the same name by design.

eg File has getTemperature and then getTemperature is executed in the class.

I am using the following Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

The code is:

```
 if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("SF   <retailername> retailername <manName> man");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    GetSoogrData wa = new GetSoogrData();
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            Class c  = wa.getClass();


            c.getDeclaredMethod(line, null);
        }
```

The compiler gives warnings about a Raw Type (Class is a  Raw Type) and also warnings on the getDeclaredMethod saying about Type. The class is just declared:

```
public class GetSoogrData {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> wordDictionary =   new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private File inputFile;

    private File outputFile;
    private String retailerName;
    private String man;
    private String[] word;

    public void getTemperature() {
        System.out.println("device temp");
    }
```

I am testing with getTemperature.

I have tried a few versions of the code and there is no error but no result either. The code just seems to ignore the method completely. I tested without the getDeclaredMethod and it worked OK, so the method can be reached and the class instantiated. Hence the error lies with the actual getDeclaredMethod. I saw the Java version can affect this.

Has anyone any solution?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the method. Once you _get_ the method, you still have to _call_ it.

Comment: what is the content of `line`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing something like:

```
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(line);
method.invoke(wa);//this will call method whatever is there in your line method without any parameters
```

Comment: Actually, there is a `getDeclaredMethod` method in `Class`.  It just needs the right arguments.

Comment: Yeah just modified was confused between method and methods.

Comment: That all worked great. My real app has some parameters and when I try that it keeps failing (saying no method). Here is the code:   java.lang.reflect.Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(crawlMethod, null);
        manparts = (List<ManPart>) m.invoke(wa, (String) url); the crawler method accepts the url. The error is caused by the method() being different to method(String url). I have attempted various parameter settings from google searching but they have all failed. The actual method just accepts String url and returns List<PartMan>. Any help is welcome!

Comment: instead of passing null, use String.class

Answer (score 1):

First, The line:

```
c.getDeclaredMethod(line, null);
```

Should be:

```
c.getDeclaredMethod(line);
```

`getDeclaredMethod` receives a varargs array of `Class` objects, so your non-parameterized method should receive an empty array, not `null`.

Second, you should `invoke` the method object after getting it, using `Method.invoke(Object)`.

Anyway, debugging would probably be solving your problem. You could just run line by line to see if the code line is "ignored", then you could probably figure out what's wrong with your code...

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my second query at [getDeclaredMethod doesn't work, NoSuchMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465407/getdeclaredmethod-doesnt-work-nosuchmethodexception) - the solution involves adding String.class as an argument.