# Java reflection error: NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

I just read about reflection and decided to give it a try, but I seem to run into an error I can not find the cause for.

I got the following code in a class:

```
String hashType = "md5";
Method method = DigestUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod(hashType + "Hex");
String hash = (String) method.invoke("hello");
```

This piece of code that should store the hashed string into the variable hash, throws the following error at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex()
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
        at stringHasher.stringHasher.hashString(stringHasher.java:37)
```

According to the API documentation the method does exist: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html

Beside not understanding what is the cause of this error I also don't understand why I need to cast the returned value by the method to a String as the API states it returns a string (should type safety not be in the hands of the programmer in this case instead of enforced by eclipse?).

Comment: There are 3 different methods called `md5Hex` but all of them have a parameter. You are not declaring any parameter in the `getDeclaredMethod` call so it looks for a method without parameters `md5Hex()` that doesn't exist. But may I ask why you are using reflection in this case at all? If you want type safety directly calling the method and not using reflection seems a better solution.

Comment: As @OHGODSPIDERS said, there are 3 methods called md5Hex. So try this one: 
`DigestUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod(hashType + "Hex", String.class);`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465407/getdeclaredmethod-doesnt-work-nosuchmethodexception

Comment: I am using it because I would like to try it out and see if I can get it to work. I might use it to reduce code at a later time. How would declare parameters in the getDeclaredMethod call?

Comment: @BilalELCHAMI thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an argument type as a second argument in `getDeclaredMethod`. And you should pass something (better `null`) as a first argument to invoke a static method.

```
String hashType = "md5";
Method method = DigestUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod(hashType + "Hex", String.class);
String hash = (String) method.invoke(null, "hello");
```

And for a non-static methods you can do that:

```
DigestUtils instance = new DigestUtils();
String hash = (String) method.invoke(instance, "hello");
```

Comment: for static methods you should use null - but argument is just ignored so it is not a big issue and you can use anything. But using any arguments looks like maybe it is target of this method.